# open cash drawer with php_printer.dll library PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to open the cash drawer using the library php_printer.dll php but I can not get it. definitely I have to open it from php or javascript because the development is finished.

Printer is Epson tm-t20

I appreciate the assistance given.

Answer (score 0):

do you have it printing properly?

if so you need to be able to write raw data to the printer and send the cash drawer open code for that particular printer which can be found at http://keyhut.com/popopen.htm. You will then need to write these to the print stream as character codes not integers so for example code(27,112,0,25,250) is

```
Print(Chr(27) & Chr(112) & Chr(0) & Chr(25) & Chr(250))
```

my company developed a POS system that was cloud based. We simply developed a small print client application in VB.net that would get print jobs from the server through a PHP script and print them.